# The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/myaAppGateway' under resource group 'myResourceGroupAG' was not found

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on setting up an application getaway with a group of backend app services. I am in the final configuration steps of configuring a listener, but first I need to set Application Gateway to support key vault reference certificates. I follow this guide from the official Microsoft documentation: [Key Vault Azure Role-Based Access Control Permissions Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_HybridNetworking#key-vault-azure-%20role-based-access-control-permission-model)

via azure powershell, but i get this series of errors. In the case of getAzApplicationGateway, I have already verified that the name in which my resource is located is correct. As for get-AzApplicationGateweyIdentity and Add-Az-ApplicationGatewaySslCertifacate, I get: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ApplicationGateway' because it is null. I can't find the cause for this error, am I entering the wrong argument?

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Your first command in the posted snippet "Get-AzApplicationGateway" doesn't find your gateway.
At least in the snipped provided you don't give -name and -ResourceGroupName as strings, meaning in " ".
Wenn I run your commands with strings where they are required it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the below command directly, I got the same error.

```cs
$appgw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name YourApplicationGatewayName -ResourceGroupName YourRGName
```

[image]

- First, we need to create an Application Gateway.
  [image]
- Create a Managed Identity.
- After creating the `ApplicationGateway` and `ManagedIdentity`, now run the below commands.

```cs
 $appgw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name YourApplicationGatewayName -ResourceGroupName YourRGName
 Set-AzApplicationGatewayIdentity -ApplicationGateway $appgw -UserAssignedIdentityId "/subscriptions/YourSubscriptionID/resourceGroups/YourRGName/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/MyYourManagedIdentityName"
```

[image]

- Create a `KeyVault` and `certificate` by following the steps from the document and run the below command to

```cs
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "YourKeyVaultName" -Name "YourCertificateName"

Add-AzApplicationGatewaySslCertificate -KeyVaultSecretId $secretId -ApplicationGateway $appgw -Name $secret.Name
```

- Before running the below command make sure you have created the `Access policy` with `Get` selected on `Secret permissions` and provided the created Managed Identity.

```cs
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw
```